# How to close and reopen docker terminal

Tags: bash, docker, ubuntu-14.04

I am installing nvm inside docker. After I've finished installing it says to run `echo ". ~/.nvm/nvm.sh" >> ~/.bash_profile` and then **close and reopen** terminal.

I think the above procedure updates bash profile and let me access `nvm.sh` from bash with `nvm` command. But, to do this, I have to close and reopen bash/terminal.

Is there anyway to do this or I've to stop docker container and then run it again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`~/.bash_profile` is sourced only by login instances of `bash`, presumably thats why they have said you to logout and then login.

If the only change you have made to `~/.bash_profile` is adding the `. ~/.nvm/nvm.sh`, then you can have the same effect as far as the shell is concerned by `source`-ing the file in the current shell instance:

```
. ~/.nvm/nvm.sh
```

This of course covers only the `bash`'s aspect, not `docker` as a whole.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe this will help with docker, to run scripts in running docker image, you can attach it to bash, reopen the instance with new profile:

```
docker ps -all #to get container id
docker exec -i -t 38ad5f94df4d /bin/bash
```

`-t` container id or container name